# Parent has unspecified height, how can I make a child inherit?

Tags: css, html, parent-child

I'm trying to make a child element `inherit` the `height` of the parent, but using `height:100%` won't work, probably because the height of the parent is unknown. It depends on the size of the post.

I want you to hover the parent, at which point the child element becomes visible and takes up the exact same space as the parent element.

Is there any way this is possible? Preferably css only.

Thanks in advance!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Va8/)

Comment: Can you share your try and code?

Comment: may you share your code and create a fiddle for us so we can help: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: it's not the same since I can't set the parent's height. I added a fiddle.

Comment: Flexbox will allow you to make an element stretch to fill its parent container. I don't have time to build a test case for it now though.

Comment: Thank's @Quintin, adding flex-grow:1 on child and display:flex on parent are working for the height, though the width is messed up now, but I'll figure it out! Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Applying `height:100%` won't actually do anything if its parent's height is set to `auto`, which is the default value if it is not specified.

When an element has its height set to auto, its height actually reflects how tall it must be to accommodate all of its children.

So, if the child of that element has a height of 100%, you are specifying that the height must be calculated based on the height of the parent. But the parent's height is determined by the height of the child...which is determined by the height of the parent...

This infinite loop cannot exist, so in these circumstances, the child's height will revert back to `auto`.

Comment: That's a better explanation of the problem then the question provides, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question is how can a child inherit the parent's unspecified height, is it not? Am I not describing how that is not possible?

Comment: No, you're explaining why `height: 100%` doesn't work. (And it is possible)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But is there any way to solve the problem? At first I didn't have height set to aut in the parent div, but then I thought maybe the child can only take over the height if it's specified, so I added that line, but it obviously doesn't work either

Comment: As Quentin indicates, Flexbox is a solution, but since IE9 and below don't support it, you'll have to judge how important that is to you (and it's usually important given IE's market share) . But as you've described your case, there is no solution that I can see save trying a Flexbox polyfill, but I've never used one so I can't tell you how successful you would be.

Comment: I've been playing around with flexbox, and I can't really make it work either, maybe I'll just have to try something completely different.